# How to pick specfic data from json response javascript

Tags: javascript, json

## How to pick specific data from JSON response javascript

### Background-Info

I'm trying to create an application to view data from haveibeenpawned's API. I don't want to call the API directly from javascript so I made my own API to act as a middle man which works just fine.

### Issue

When I call the API it returns all the data but when I try to select that data (specifically Domain) with `data2.Domain` it returns undefined. Now I also used another  API of mine to get data from haveibeenpawned but Different information and when I pass data like that it works and doesn't return undefined.

### What I've tried

- I've tried making this an object as some people suggested by doing `JSON.parse(data2)[0].username` but that just gives me another error and if the method I tried before works with another part of the API I don't understand why it won't work here.

---

### Json returned (the API that doesn't work with data.DATA_I_WANT)

```
{
    "Name": "Canva",
    "Title": "Canva",
    "Domain": "canva.com",
    "BreachDate": "2019-05-24",
    "AddedDate": "2019-08-09T14:24:01Z",
    "ModifiedDate": "2019-08-09T14:24:01Z",
    "PwnCount": 137272116,
    "Description": "In May 2019, the graphic design tool website <a href=\"https://support.canva.com/contact/customer-support/may-24-security-incident-faqs/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Canva suffered a data breach</a> that impacted 137 million subscribers. The exposed data included email addresses, usernames, names, cities of residence and passwords stored as bcrypt hashes for users not using social logins. The data was provided to HIBP by a source who requested it be attributed to \"JimScott.Sec@protonmail.com\".",
    "LogoPath": "https://haveibeenpwned.com/Content/Images/PwnedLogos/Canva.png",
    "DataClasses": [
        "Email addresses",
        "Geographic locations",
        "Names",
        "Passwords",
        "Usernames"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsFabricated": false,
    "IsSensitive": false,
    "IsRetired": false,
    "IsSpamList": false,
    "IsMalware": false
}
```

---

### Json returned (The API that does work with data.DATA_I_WANT)

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Canva"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Minehut"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pixlr"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Quidd"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Teespring"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Zynga"
    }
]
```

---

### My javascript (sorry if its not good never used JS before)

```
                        function getData(){
                            console.log('getting data')
                            const queryString = window.location.search;
                            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
                            const email = urlParams.get('email')

                            var myArray = []
                            var status = 0

                            var URL = 'https://securityvisit.api.anonyomail.com/search/email?email=' + email

                            $.ajax({
                                method:"GET",
                                url: URL,
                                complete:function(response){
                                    status = response.status
                                    myArray = response.responseJSON
                                    buildTable(myArray, status)
                                    console.log(myArray)
                                    console.log(status)
                                }
                            })

                            function getMoreData(service){
                                var myArray = []
    
                                var URL = 'https://securityvisit.api.anonyomail.com/search/service?service=' + service
    
                                $.ajax({
                                    method:"GET",
                                    url: URL,
                                    complete:function(response){
                                        myArray = response.responseJSON
                                        console.log(myArray)
                                    }
                                })

                                return(myArray)
                            }

                            function buildTable(data, status){
                                var table = document.getElementById('dataTable')
                                var info = document.getElementById('main_info')

                                console.log('Status: ' + status)
                                if(status == 500){
                                    var html = `
                                    <h1 class="" style="color:limegreen ">Email not comprimised!</h1>
                                    <br>
                                    <h3 style="color:white;">No data to be shown</h3>
                                    `
                                }else{
                                    console.log('Displaying compromising information')
                                    // var html = `
                                    // <h1 class="" style="color:red">Email is comprimised!</h1>
                                    // <br>
                                    // `
                                    
                                    // info.innerHTML += html
                                    table.innerHTML = null
                                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                       var data2 = getMoreData(data[i].Name)
                            
                                    var row = `<tr>
                                        <td><img src='${data2.LogoPath}'></img></td>
                                        <td>${data[i].Name}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.username}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.BreachDate}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.Domain}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.DataClasses}</td>
                                        </tr>`
                                    table.innerHTML += row
                                    console.log('Domain: ' + data2.Domain)
                                    } 
                                }

                                
                            }
```

---

### My HTML

```
                <div class="p-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Logo</th>
                            <th>Service</th>
                            <th>Compromised On</th>
                            <th>Domain</th>
                            <th>Compromised Data</th>
                            <th>Comprimised information</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tbody id="dataTable">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <tbody id="main_info">
                    </tbody>
                </div>
```

---

### What my end goal is

My end goal is just to get the data from my API displayed on my HTML table also my API doesn't have a password protecting it yet so feel free to make calls to it to test out why its not working.

Comment: This question is a little too broad. What part of the JS codebase does the error get thrown in, and which parts display the returned JSONs.

Comment: oh sorry, the function getData gets a list of names that have been compromised and the function getMoreData takes that name and displays even more information on the service and exploit that happened., @OvidijusParsiunas

Comment: The issue is that `var row` will return undefined for the values returned from the getMoreData function @OvidijusParsiunas

Comment: What data does ```data2``` contain?

Comment: data2 contains the returned data from the function `getMoreData` @OvidijusParsiunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMoreData` always return an empty array because the value is updated when the promise is resolved

you have to return the promise generated by `$.ajax` and `await` for the result

like this

```js
function getData() {
  console.log('getting data')
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const email = urlParams.get('email')

  var myArray = []
  var status = 0

  var URL = 'https://securityvisit.api.anonyomail.com/search/email?email=' + email

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: URL,
    complete: function(response) {
      status = response.status
      myArray = response.responseJSON
      buildTable(myArray, status)
      console.log(myArray)
      console.log(status)
    }
  })
}

function getMoreData(service) {
  var myArray = []

  var URL = 'https://securityvisit.api.anonyomail.com/search/service?service=' + service

  return $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: URL,
    complete: function(response) {
      myArray = response.responseJSON
      console.log(myArray)
    }
  })


}

async function buildTable(data, status) {
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable')
  var info = document.getElementById('main_info')

  console.log('Status: ' + status)
  if (status == 500) {
    var html = `<h1 class="" style="color:limegreen ">Email not comprimised!</h1><br><h3 style="color:white;">No data to be shown</h3>`
  } else {
    console.log('Displaying compromising information')

    table.innerHTML = null
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var data2 = await getMoreData(data[i].Name)

      var row = `<tr>
                                        <td><img src='${data2.LogoPath}'></img></td>
                                        <td>${data[i].Name}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.username}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.BreachDate}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.Domain}</td>
                                        <td>${data2.DataClasses}</td>
                                        </tr>`
      table.innerHTML += row
      console.log('Domain: ' + data2.Domain)
    }
  }


}
getData()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-2">
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Logo</th>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Compromised On</th>
      <th>Domain</th>
      <th>Compromised Data</th>
      <th>Comprimised information</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="dataTable">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <tbody id="main_info">
  </tbody>
</div>
```